# Can Shazam undress himself?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam, shazam-2019

There's this funny scene in *Shazam!* (2019) in which Shazam had to go to the bathroom and he couldn't figure out how to get his stuff out of the way. Finally, he had to transform back into his original form to pee.

Is Shazam's suit part of his body? Or can he take it off?

Comment: If you choose to add it back in again I won't roll it back but I really don't think that paragraph adds anything to the question and is at the very least borderline innapropriate.

Comment: Are you asking about just the Shazam character from the 2019 movie, or also about Shazam from the comic books as well as Shazam from the TV series?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In *Whiz Comics* #50 (1944), Shazam (Captain Marvel at that time) undresses to go for a swim:

[image: Shazam takes a dive]

Comment: You've failed to include the funniest part, the cover; https://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/gone_swimming_1723.jpg

Comment: I truly want to know more about the story here, is this comic available somewhere, somehow?

Comment: @André I found a couple more pages here: https://dochermes.livejournal.com/1708768.html

Comment: @ André A reprint is available for a much lower price than the original  https://www.amazon.com/Whiz-Comics-50-Starring-Captain/dp/1514242621

Comment: @Wastrel the original is 10 cents, and the reprint is 18 dollars

Comment: @theonlygusti Did you adjust for inflation?

Comment: @Valorum, ...because there's _always_ a barrel handy when you need one. Only puzzling thing is, I thought that whenever you found a barrel, it came with a pair of suspenders attached. https://brevity.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/man-wearing-barrel-and-suspenders-after-divorce1.jpg

Comment: @SolomonSlow Superheroes don't need no damn suspenders.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation 10 cents in 1944 is apparently equivalent to 1.38 dollars today. So still much cheaper than 18 dollars. I am just not sure what Wastrel meant with his comment's phrasing.

Comment: @SolomonSlow In real life too - just look up the [Rector of Stiffkey](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12553/17).

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm not sure why you think he was comparing that price to the original price.  It seems pretty obvious he was comparing the reprint price to what you would have to spend if you wanted to buy one of the original copies right now (which after some brief searching, would appear to be a few hundred dollars). Though it is a little strange he felt the need to point out and advertise the reprint, as if anyone was looking to buy the original for non-collecting reasons.

Comment: @Valorum: the bad guy on the cover really should have been saying, "Μολὼν λαβέ" :-)

Comment: The '10 cent' original would now cost around $525.

Comment: @theonlygusti  What I meant was that you can't go back in time and get it for ten cents any more. That phrasing came naturally to me because I used to collect comics. Funny comment, though.